# Window functions (lead/lag) with collections in Oracle SQL (PL/SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, window-functions

I want to port a SQL script which exists in PostgreSQL to Oracle SQL.
Here is sample data:

```
NR                      GRD DT
00000000000000000001    06  01.01.13
00000000000000000001    06  01.01.13
00000000000000000001    21  01.01.13
00000000000000000002    06  01.01.13
00000000000000000002    21  01.01.13
00000000000000000004    01  31.03.13
```

Here is my simplified code:

```
CREATE TYPE tbl_array AS TABLE OF NVARCHAR2(4000);

with prep as (
Select
    nr
    , cast(collect(grd) as tbl_array) grds
from
    test_table
group by
    nr                    
)
select 
    prep.*
    , lead(grds) over (order by nr) as lead_grds
from 
    prep
```

But the window function does not work. I get the following error message:

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got ORACLEANALYTICS.TBL_ARRAY

Is it because of the created type? How can I solve this issue?
In step two I want to check the intersection of the collections with others (already working) so I need them. Is this somehow possible?

Cheers
Chris

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: You should focus on what you want to accomplish.  What results are you trying to obtain?

Comment: The question is very simple. OP wants to get lead/lag function on column grd which is user-defined type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER()` to simulate `LAG/LEAD`:

```
with prep as (
  select
    nr, CAST(collect(grd) AS tbl_array) grds,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY nr) AS rn
  from tab
  group by nr                    
)
select p.nr, p.grds, p2.grds AS lead_grds
    --, lead(grds) over (order by nr) as lead_grds
from prep p
LEFT JOIN prep p2
  ON p2.rn = p.rn +1;
```

Output from prep:

```
┌──────────────────────┬────────────────────────────────┬────┐
│          NR          │              GRDS              │ RN │
├──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────┤
│ 00000000000000000001 │ HR.TBL_ARRAY('06', '21', '06') │  1 │
│ 00000000000000000002 │ HR.TBL_ARRAY('06', '21')       │  2 │
│ 00000000000000000004 │ HR.TBL_ARRAY('01')             │  3 │
└──────────────────────┴────────────────────────────────┴────┘
```

Output of entire query:

```
┌──────────────────────┬──────────────────────────────┬──────────────────────────┐
│          NR          │             GRDS             │        LEAD_GRDS         │
├──────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────┤
│ 00000000000000000001 │HR.TBL_ARRAY('06', '21', '06')│ HR.TBL_ARRAY('06', '21') │
│ 00000000000000000002 │HR.TBL_ARRAY('06', '21')      │ HR.TBL_ARRAY('01')       │
│ 00000000000000000004 │HR.TBL_ARRAY('01')            │                          │
└──────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────┘
```

---

Equivalent in PostgreSQL:

```
WITH prep AS (
  SELECT NR, ARRAY_AGG(GRD) AS grds
  FROM tab
  GROUP BY NR
)
SELECT prep.*, LEAD(grds) OVER(ORDER BY nr) AS lead_grds
FROM prep;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=bb01e345829185a84a205133d35188d6)**

Comment: Works, thank you very much! But could you please tell me, is it generally not possible to use lead/lag with user defined types?

Comment: Another question: I want to create a table and get the error message: ORA-22913: must specify table name for nested table column or attribute. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: @csnr I suppose you cannot use LEAD/LAG with collection type(but I don't have link so doc so it is solely my opinion). As for second question you should ask new question. I guess you want something like `CREATE TABLE tab AS query`. It is out of scope of this case.

Comment: Ok thanks. Problem solved. Yes I had to create a table and specify the column type in advance.